# Sharing objects between only two activities using Dagger 2.0

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have multiple activities extending **BaseActivity**. Each activity has own component and module. Those components extend **BaseActivityComponent** which has own **BaseActivityModule**.
Now I have two activities that I want to be able to inject objects that other activities will not be able to.

How can I do that?

I tried creating a base component and base module just for those two activities, but that gave me error:

> MyModule depends on a scoped components in a non-hierarchical order

Now I want **AdvertAdvanced** to be shared by two activities.

This component is used by one of the two activities:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(
        dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
        modules = {
                BaseActivityModule.class,
                MainActivityModule.class
        }
)
public interface MainActivityComponent extends BaseActivityComponent {
        void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
        MainActivityPresenter mainPresenter();
        AdvertAdvanced advertAdvanced();
}
```

As base component for each activity I have the following:

```
    @ActivityScope
    @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = BaseActivityModule.class)
    public interface BaseActivityComponent extends ApplicationComponent {

        BaseActivity baseActivity();
        Navigator navigator();
        KeyboardAction keyboardAction();

    }
```

Application component:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(
            modules = {
                    ApplicationModule.class
            }
    )
    public interface ApplicationComponent {

        void inject(BaseActivity activity);

        Context context();
        ApiService apiService();
        Picasso picasso();

    }
```

This is how a module for activities looks like:

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {

    private AdvertAdvanced advertAdvanced;

    public MainActivityModule() {
        advertAdvanced = new AdvertAdvanced();
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    MainActivityPresenter provideActivityPresenter(****) {
        return ****;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    AdvertAdvanced advertAdvanced() {
        return advertAdvanced;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: @NeilMasson added some code. Let me know if you need more

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a new component `AdvertActivityComponent`, with a component dependency of `BaseActivityComponent`, with a subscope such as `@AdvertisedScope`. Your current `BaseActivityComponent` should have its own scope, such as `@BaseScope`, and your `MainActivityComponent` should depend on `AdvertActivityComponent` with a `@ConcreteActivityScope`.

Essentially, your scope hierarchy is:

- Application scope (`@Singleton`)
- Base Activity scope (`@BaseScope`)
- Advert Activity scope (`@AdvertScope`)
- Main Activity scope (`@ConcreteScope`)

And your components should extend one another and depend on their supercomponent as such.

Comment: Where do we keep AdvertActivityComponent instance? If we keep it at Application, it is tied to application life cycle so it lives longer than we need. If we keep it at activity, then it is limited to one activity and the other activity cannot share the objects which is the requirement of the original question.

Comment: Ah, the million dollar question. You could just throw it in `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` because it is an Activity's component.

Comment: Very interesting. How did I miss to learn about  [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())? Thank you.

Comment: If you use `AppCompatActivity` then you should use `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`

Comment: Ok. Now I studied it, I am not sure if it will help to share component instance across different activities. What I understand is when the activity is about to be destroyed, `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance` may help us to retain the instance only when we try `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()` of the _same_ activity (instance may be different), we will get that retained component. In this case, we need it in the _other_ activity. Right?

Comment: Looks like, we have to go through bundling the component through the intent used for launching other activity.

Comment: There's no way that is right. Components shouldn't be in the Intent. :|

Comment: You are right. An alternative: [This article](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/) suggests to keep the component in Application and provide a release method for the activity (last one) to call when it is done. Ugly as well and won't work if the first activity comes looking for the component again.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the previous Activity exists in the stack. After low memory condition, only the fore-front Activity is recreated initially, the previous Activity is recreated on Back navigation..